# kendo-grid doesn't create rows in spec test

Tags: angular, jasmine, kendo-grid

I am writing an angular spec test to test a component that uses a kendo-grid. My component gets a list of data as an input, and the data source of the kendo-grid is a get function that builds the data to be used in the kendo-grid. In my spec test it does not display any rows unless I define a static data source for the kendo-grid.

Here is my opening tag for the kendo-grid element:

```
<kendo-grid
  #grid
  [data]=gridView
  scrollable="virtual"
  id="shipmentGrid"
  [sortable]="{allowUnsort: false, mode:'single'}"
  [sort]="sort"
  [resizable]=true
  style="width:100%;"
  (sortChange)="sortChange($event)"
  (pageChange)="pageChange($event)"
  [skip]="skip"
  [style]="gridHeightStyle"
  [rowHeight]="35"
  [pageSize]="pageSize"
>
```

Here is the get gridView function in my component.ts that returns the data for kendo-grid:

```
@Input() public shipments: Shipment[] = [];

get gridView(): GridDataResult {
    return {
      data: this.shipments.slice(this.skip, this.skip + this.pageSize),
      total: this.shipments.length
    };
  }
```

When I set my kendo-grid data like I do above the spec test never creates any rows and instead the row for kendoGridNoRecordsTemplate is displayed.

But when I set the kendo-grid datasource to some constant value it works:

```
<kendo-grid
  #grid
  [data]=staticList
  scrollable="virtual"
  id="shipmentGrid"
  [sortable]="{allowUnsort: false, mode:'single'}"
  [sort]="sort"
  [resizable]=true
  style="width:100%;"
  (sortChange)="sortChange($event)"
  (pageChange)="pageChange($event)"
  [skip]="skip"
  [style]="gridHeightStyle"
  [rowHeight]="35"
  [pageSize]="pageSize"
>

staticList = {
   data: [{shipmentDate: new Date(), shipmentQuantity: 5}],
   total: 1
}
```

How can I get my spec test to work using the @input shipments and the get gridView() function? It's almost like when I set the input shipments array during my test the empty grid is already created and it never recreates with my new shipments list. I'm not putting my individual columns because the grid creates correctly in real life, it's just when I test the component the kendo-grid isn't creating its rows with my shipments array that I create in the test.

Comment: Are you defining `shipments` before the first `fixture.detectChanges()` after `TestBed.createComponent(...)`. The first `fixture.detectChanges()` is when `ngOnInit` is called and I am thinking the `shipments` should be defined before this call.

Comment: I was setting the shipments array in each test with different values so yes that was the problem. Setting it in the 'BeforeEach' section made it build the grid correctly. But now I have to use the same shipments data in each test. Is there some way to allow for different data in each test?

Comment: Maybe try changing the shipments array and then call fixture.detectChanges(). I am hoping that will work.

Comment: @AliF50 It seemed once I called fixture.detectChanges() the first time it's when ngOnInit ran and then calling it again after that never worked. So I instead do not call it until after each individual test is setup. So I run it once in each test instead of in the beforeEach()

Comment: Yes, the first `fixture.detectChanges()` calls `ngOnInit`. Subsequent `fixture.detectChanges()` just update the HTML but will not call `ngOnInit`. To call `ngOnInit` again, do `component.ngOnInit()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was I was setting the shipments data in each test, but I was already calling fixture.detectChanges(); in my beforeEach() section of the test suite... Moving the fixture.detectChanges(); call from the beforeEach() setup and into each individual test after setting my data fixed my problem.